# How to get No Records from SSRS to ASPX/ASCX

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, export-to-excel

I have a SSRS report and I just used it from my aspx and export it into excel directly without having ReportViewer. Now I want to check whether my DataSet having value or not. I can able to call the SP that I have used in SSRS to get the count. But I dont want to use that. Since I dont want to export to excel when there is no record or dataset is empty...!

Does anyone have any idea about how to return "No Records" from SSRS to ASPX/ASCX?

Answer (score 1):

A simpler method would be to

1. fetch the data from your stored procedure in your .net code
2. check the no of records in the dataset
3. If there are records, pass it to the report
4. If not, show a "No Records" message

Here is how you can set the data source

```
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(
    new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource(
    "MyData", dataset.Tables[0]));
reportViewer.RefreshReport();
```

You could now export this data to excel.